# native compilation & build linux kernel embedded system

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, microcontroller

I have cross-compiled a kernel, in an autodidactic manner, on a raspberry pi twice in the past.
This kind of things can sometimes a pain in the ... But fortunately there are some step-by-step tutorials.

So I am wondering whether there are general steps that have to be taken and that are the same on all the embedded systems (rpi, beaglebone, atmega controllers, etc...) in order to successfully cross-compile the kernel and make everything work?

My guess:

1) download the kernel source code

2) generate a .config file (which seems necessary)

3) get into the blue screen to do additional adjustements
   with e.g.: make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- menuconfig

4) compile the kernel:
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-

5) put it on the SD card or anything else

Would this be a correct general scheme for any cross-compilation on an embedded system?
Sorry for my ignorance, as I mentioned above I learned it by myself.

I would like to be able to setup a kernel on any embedded device.
Any more information or explanation would be more than welcome! As it seems this kind of things can always be done in multiple manners, it gets me confused.

Comment: There is a session on it in the RPI site http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation#2._Cross_compiling_from_Linux

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your first two steps haven't much to do with *cross-compiling*. In fact it just comes down to having a *cross toolchain* targeting your platform correctly installed on your system.

The `CROSS_COMPILE` make variable of the kernel doesn't do anything other than prepending the string it is set to to any toolchain command (like e.g. `gcc` for compiling), so if your *cross toolchain* is installed in your search path, it would be enough to set it to just the desired [target triplet](http://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet) with added hyphen, e.g. in your case `CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-`. This would lead to using the command `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` for compiling and so on.

For other embedded devices, you might need different cross toolchains (depending on their architecture), but the general process would indeed stay the same.